# Laravel could not find second driver

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm building a webapp which have two databases:
**First**: Database for user registrations, sign up etc. / in **MySQL**
**Second**: Database for the stock market data / in **PostgreSQL**

---

First database (MySQL) works without any problem.
But the second one (PostgreSQL) **doesn't work**.

---

This is my env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=panel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=pgsql
DB_HOST_SECOND=localhost
DB_PORT_SECOND=5432
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=assets_daily_info
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=postgres
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=1234
```

And here is the database config php file:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

I made a Model where I want to get data from PostgreSQL database:

```
    namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thepage extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'pgsql';
    protected $table = 'queue_stats';
    protected $fillable = [
        'buyqueue', 'sellqueue', 'timestamp',
    ];
}
```

And finally, here is the controller:

```
class Thepage Controller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $queues = Thepage::all();
        return view('pages.queue-stats',compact('queues'));
    }
}
```

The problem is that laravel can't find the driver, it just shows:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select * from "queue_stats")

I double checked apache's and php's .ini files, extension pdo_pgsql and pgsql are uncommented in both files.
I tried clear cache and config cache, nothing happened and I still get this annoying error.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `php -m` show the extension?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter yes, pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql

Comment: Are you using php-fpm? If so, what does `phpinfo();` show if you add that like near the top `public/index.php` then access your homepage in a browser? You should see a bunch of infomation dumped and a section listing the enabled extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Execute these commands :

```
composer update
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Make sure to uncomment/add `extension=pdo_pgsql.so` in your php.ini file of your running PHP version.

Comment: I've uncommented that

Comment: @MostafaSafarian, stop your laravel project and reserve it again with ```php artisan serve``` or restart Apache/Nginx if you're working on linux

Comment: done all the steps, but still no luck. it still shows `Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from "queue_stats")`